# CSS - my food menu works well in Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome

Tags: css

My food menu works perfectly in Firefox and IE, but not at all on Chrome. The dt tag overlaps with other dd tags. I have tried to search from the question list, but cannot get the right one. I many times tried to play around with float and overflow, but have been unable to address this problem.

Your suggestions would be appreciated. I really want to stop scratching my head, since I have been doing this for several months.

```
#menucontent dt {
float: left;
padding-right: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#menucontent dd.price {
float: right;
color: #E1DEDE;
}

#menucontent dd.ingredients {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
color: #FAD98A;
}
```

My food menu can be clicked from this link
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13748701/dinner.html

Its CSS source is here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13748701/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `overflow: hidden;` to your `dl` element in css :

```
#menucontent dl {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mateusz. I can believe that my long time issue can be addressed by adding a new element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: get rid of all the empty `<p>`-tags! They are not necessary. Want to created spaces between elements? Use `margin`!

For your problem: add a `clear: both;` to h2. So you get this:

```
h2 {
  padding: 3px 15px 0px 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #F7E4B5;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bram. I also tried your way and it works perfectly. I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: To be quite honest, I would prefer my way over Mateusz' because overflow:hidden is often seen as a 'quick way out' to solve your problems, but in the end you often end up with quite some problems. Well, at least that's my experience. Good luck with your site!